# Videojs-contrib-hls returning undefined on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, video.js, http-live-streaming

I'm using videojs and videojs-contrib-hls to display multibitrate HLS VOD streams. The Player is working fine except on safari. on Safari when I:

```
console.log(player.tech({ IWillNotUseThisInPlugins: true }).hls);
```

I get undefined. Chrome and Firefox work. 
Is there any special workflow to consider on safari since HLS is native?

My goal is to create a video rendition switcher for the different m3u8 files.

videojs version 5.11.6
videojs-contrib-hls version 3.5.3

Any help is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well according to this [document by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) (8. chapter) and [this github thread](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/issues/193) there is no way of controlling the different renditions switching. Basically safari will do it by itself when it sees right and since it (or quicktime) does not expose any API to do that, we can only trust and pray for the best…